# Paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, openflow, ryu

I just encountered the problem with connecting the SDN switch, pica 8 3290, with ryu's of-config library and python paramiko library.

Here's the traceback msg:

```
=================================================================================
xdn41o71:ryu Mac$ sudo ryu-manager ryu/app/of_config.py
Password:
loading app ryu/app/of_config.py
Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.0p1)
Authentication (password) successful!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ryu-manager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ryu==3.20.1', 'console_scripts', 'ryu-manager')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/cmd/manager.py", line 88, in main
    app_mgr.load_apps(app_lists)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/base/app_manager.py", line 390, in load_apps
    cls = self.load_app(app_cls_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/base/app_manager.py", line 366, in load_app
    mod = utils.import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/utils.py", line 91, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Mac/ryu/ryu/app/of_config.py", line 9, in <module>
    unknown_host_cb=lambda host, fingeprint: True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/lib/of_config/capable_switch.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.netconf = connect(*self._connect_args, **self._connect_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/contrib/ncclient/manager.py", line 67, in connect_ssh
    session.connect(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ryu/contrib/ncclient/transport/ssh.py", line 208, in connect
    c.invoke_subsystem("netconf")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 60, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 254, in invoke_subsystem
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1086, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
===============================================================================
```

I've googled the problem, paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.,
however, there isn't any appropriate solution to my problem.

Anyone can give me some instructions to solve this problem?

Comment: Its hard to help you when you can't publish the code that did this. I understand why this is the case, but it makes helping you out rather difficult.

Comment: You tried to invoke a subsystem called "netconf" on the target server. That subsystem doesn't exist on the server so it closed the channel. "netconf" isn't a standard subsystem on most sshd's. I don't know if it's supposed to be there on an SDN, but maybe the question is why the pica 8 3290 doesn't have this subsystem or whether ryu is the right tool for the job.

Comment: sorry for that I don't have the permission to post photos of complete msg. Here's the link i discuss the issue. I think there may have much more info, plz check it :https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/513#issuecomment-94160115

Comment: could anyone give me any advice to try solve this problem, plz